# List type do not fit in JSON serialization

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have an issue to put JSON object into another JSON object through subsequent class object. I kind of understand what is the problem but do not manage to solve it.
The output expected would be:

```
{
  "txs": [
    {
      "size": 225,
      "time": 1593700974, 
      "input": {'address': '3QJ1oLLQ4W1S4MxefB13d5YsrVYmCosNz', 'value': 234}
    },...
}
```

The code:

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.transactions = [Transaction(tx) for tx in a['txs']]
    def to_json(self, **kwargs):
        transactions = [{'time': t.time, 'size': t.size, 'input':{t.inputs}} for t in self.transactions]
        return json.dumps({'txs': transactions}, **kwargs)

class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.time = t['time']
        self.size = t['size']
        self.inputs = [Input(i) for i in t['inputs']]

class Input:
    def __init__(self, i):
        obj = i.get('prev_out')
        if obj is not None:
            self.value = obj['value']
            if 'addr' in obj:
                self.address = obj['addr']

def get_address(address):
    resource = 'address/{0}?format=json'.format(address)
    response = util.call_api(resource)
    json_response = json.loads(response)
    return Address(json_response)

p = get_address('****************************')
frame = p.to_json(indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_explo.py", line 16, in <module>
    frame = p.to_json(indent=2, sort_keys=True)
  File "/Users/delalma/Documents/MARKET_RISK/python/explorer.py", line 285, in to_json
    transactions = [{'time': t.time, 'size': t.size, 'input':{t.inputs}} for t in self.transactions]
  File "/Users/delalma/Documents/MARKET_RISK/python/explorer.py", line 285, in <listcomp>
    transactions = [{'time': t.time, 'size': t.size, 'input':{t.inputs}} for t in self.transactions]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add the internal JSON object with the following code.

```
def to_json(self, **kwargs):
    transactions = [{'time': t.time, 'size': t.size, 'input':  [{'value': i.value, 'address': i.address} for i in t.inputs]}  for t in self.transactions]
    return json.dumps({'txs': transactions}, **kwargs)
```